# Jquery: Add form validation to only those fields that are present in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which has certain elements that are required. I am validating the form elements as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function actionButton(){
            var rating_checked = jQuery('.review-control-vote').find('input[type=radio]').is(':checked');
            var customer_name = jQuery('#nickname_field').val();
            var title_checked = jQuery('.validate-one-required-by-name').is(':checked');
            var review = jQuery('#review_field').val();
            var title_other_checked = jQuery('.validate-one-required-by-name.other').is(':checked');
            var custom_title = jQuery('#summary_field').val();
            var customer_photo = jQuery(".amrev-input").val();
            if (!rating_checked || !customer_name || !title_checked || !review || !customer_photo || (title_other_checked && !custom_title)) {
                return false;
            }
            jQuery('#review-form').submit(function(event) {
                jQuery('.loginPopup_wrapper .popup-fancy.review-form>.container').addClass("complete");
                jQuery(".popupReviewSuccess").parent().show();
                event.preventDefault();
                var self = this;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    self.submit();
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
 </script>
```

The problem is that certain elements might not be present in the form depending on database configurations. Hence, the above validation shows error even when the form element is not present. I need to validate the elements only that are present in the form.

Comment: You have to validate first if the element exist, if it exists then you do the actual code, if it doesn't exist you have to assume as if it is correctly validated.

Comment: you can use normal if else. if( jQuery('.review-control-vote')) { ///} else {///}. create a variable and set it true initially. In case element is present and value is not present then set false.

Comment: Only use the jQuery Validate tag for questions about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked if an element is present in the form or not using

```
jQuery('.class_name').length
```

It returns a value greater than 0 if element is present else it returns 0.